# (WordPress) How do I shorten latest post exerpts and add a read more link

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am developing a site using the latest version of WordPress.

My site is set for the front page to show the latest posts.

The excerpts are showing the entire content of each post. **How do I shorten these and add a read more link for each one?**

Here is what is being looped out for each post:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php
    if ( is_single() ) :
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
    else :
        the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
    endif;

    if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php blogtristan_posted_on(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    <?php
    endif; ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
        the_content( sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post. */
            wp_kses( __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'blogtristan' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => array() ) ) ),
            the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
        ) );

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'blogtristan' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php blogtristan_entry_footer(); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
```

Comment: is this your index.php ? did you try the_excerpt() function ?

Comment: It's because you're using the_content() function, which returns the entire post content

Comment: Okay, I have changed it to <?php the_excerpt() ; ?>. It is now showing only some of the content. How do I add a read more link?

Answer (score 0):

As we've saw in your post's comments, to shorten the amount of text it is sufficient substitute `the_content()` function with `the_excerpt()`.

To add a "read more" link to the excerpt, it is necessary to customize the function itself. `the_excerpt` add at the end of your text the string [...].
There are some methods to accomplish that.

From https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

Customize **functions.php** with

```
/**
 * Filter the "read more" excerpt string link to the post.
 *
 * @param string $more "Read more" excerpt string.
 * @return string (Maybe) modified "read more" excerpt string.
 */
function wpdocs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return sprintf( '<a class="read-more" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
        get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
        __( 'Read More', 'textdomain' )
    );
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpdocs_excerpt_more' );
```